# WinSCP - Are multiple "put" commands in WinSCP script processed at the same time or in sequence?

Tags: winscp

Below you can safely laugh at me but just trying to see what the below command would do.

I am guessing that WinSCP will process the first put command matched by the file mask (`Morgs*.*`) and only when it finishes processing such files it’ll proceed to the next put command and process any remaining files matched by *.*. 
Or, will it create parallel connections and process both put commands at the same time, synchronously?

I am basically attempting to first process all files that begin with `Morgs`, this process will skip the .Done file, which will then get picked up at the next put command which scans for all file types at which point only the .Done file will remain…

The command instructions below will be stored in a text file and will be used like from a `sample.cmd` file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /SCRIPT="C:\morgs\secure\local-folder\Test Project\CommandInstructions.txt"
```

```
open "Morgs Secure Connection"

cd "/users/morgs/secure/folder/Test Project"
lcd "C:\morgs\secure\local-folder\Test Project"

put -delete -nopreservetime Morgs*.*

put -delete -nopreservetime *.*

bye
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How is this about Delphi?

Comment: I've removed the tag...

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP processes the commands one-by-one.

No parallel upload takes place.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl, this basically confirms that my logic will most likely work. I will test and post results...